# orientdb connect invalid password and username

Tags: linux, database, orientdb

I have a problem on my linux mint. I installed OrientDB, create a database and successfully connect to this database with password and username root root. But after closing server.sh and reopening this server.sh i couldn't connect to this database, it write that Invalid password and username. Can u say what's problem?

[image]

I think that it's with permission, but i open console.sh as superuser, want to connect and write:
*CONNECT REMOTE:LOCALHOST/SAD ROOT ROOT*
write this error.

```
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '/opt/orientdb/databases/sad' with mode=rw
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Cannot load database's configuration. The database seems to be corrupted.
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null.
```

Comment: could you browse to the database/sad directory and post the output of `ls -l` ? thx

Comment: another question: do you start the server as su user?

Comment: @IvanMainetti 
 
yes, I open server as superuser. When i connect: remote:localhost root root. It's works. Also can see list of databases. I can enter only to GratefulDeadConcerts databases, which is orinetDB databases. When i see permisiion for this database in /opt/orientdb/databases/Gratefull... it written that permisssion for #501user. Another databases with root permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, when I installed oriendb i use superuser terminal which create folder with permission as root. Now I delete the folder and reinstall it from user terminal. it works.